# No page break with tabularx in mdframed

Tags: page-breaking, mdframed

I am writing my master's thesis and I encounter a problem with `mdframed` environment.

I have a `mdframed` on several page and there is no problem. This frame is only composed with text.

I want to create another `mdframed` with `tabularx` in it. The problem is that the frame doesn't split between pages.

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
                    L'établissement des composants des processus et systèmes d'information sont illustrés ci-dessous avec les exemples présentés au point \ref{ExempleProcess} page \pageref{ExempleProcess}. Seuls les composants important sont identifiés ci-dessous. Il est évident qu'une analyse réelle doit tenter d'être la plus exhaustive possible.
                    \subsubsection*{Exemple 1 : gestion des commandes téléphoniques}

                    \textbf{Composantes du processus d'affaires :}

                    \noindent
                    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{3.8 cm}|X|}
                    \hline
                    Intrants et extrants
                        & Intrant : information relative aux besoins du client \\
                        & Extrants : information pour le processus d'analyse de la solvabilité (si le client est nouveau) ou ordre de préparation de commande \\                        
                    \hline
                    Activités
                        & Prendre de commande au téléphone par le préposé aux commandes sur le \textit{Formulaire-de-commande}, rechercher le prix de chaque article dans le catalogue, calculer le sous-total pour chaque article, préposé aux commandes, etc. \\
                    \hline
                    Sources et destinations
                        & Source : client \\
                        & Destinations : processus de d'analyse de la solvabilité (si le client est nouveau) ou entrepôt \\
                    \hline
                    Objectifs
                        & Moins de 1\% des formulaires de commande peuvent comporter des erreurs, tous \textit{Formulaire-de-commande} doit sortir du processus endéans les deux jours suivants la prise de commande, la vérification du client (nouveau ou non) de chaque commande doit être faite le matin du jour suivant la réception du formulaire, etc.\\
                    \hline
                    \end{tabularx}

                    \textbf{Composants du système d'information :}

                    \noindent
                    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{3.8 cm}|X|} 
                    \hline
                    Intrants
                        & \\
                    \hline
                    Extrants
                        & \\
                    \hline
                    Traitements
                        & \\
                    \hline
                    Bases de données
                        & \\
                    \hline
                    \end{tabularx}  

                    \subsubsection*{Exemple 2 : transferts d'ouvriers entre établissement d'une chaine horeca}

                    \textbf{Composantes du processus d'affaires :}

                    \noindent
                    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{3.8 cm}|X|} 
                    \hline
                    Intrants et extrants
                        & Intrant : information relative aux besoins du restaurant IN \\
                        & Extrant : heures prestées dans le restaurant IN et information comptable \\
                    \hline
                    Activités
                        & Communiquer son besoin de main-d'œuvre, donner son accord pour envoyer un ouvrier, prester les heures dans le restaurant IN, compléter le fichier \textit{Feuille-de-transfert}, etc.\\
                    \hline
                    Sources et destinations
                        & Source : restaurant IN \\
                        & Destinations : restaurant IN et département comptabilité \\
                    \hline
                    Objectifs
                        & Le fichier \textit{Feuille-des-transferts} doit être envoyé tous les mois à la comptabilité sans retard, les heures prestées doivent être encodées sur le système du secrétariat social le jour même de la prestation, moins de 10\% des transferts doivent être refusés, etc.\\
                    \hline
                    \end{tabularx}

                    \textbf{Composants du système d'information :}

                    \noindent
                    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{3.8 cm}|X|} 
                    \hline
                    Intrants
                        & \\
                    \hline
                    Extrants
                        & \\
                    \hline
                    Traitements
                        & \\
                    \hline
                    Bases de données
                        & \\
                    \hline
                    \end{tabularx}  

                Il convient d'être attentif au degré de détail utilisé dans la collecte d'information. Dans le premier exemple il est bien évidemment inutile de préciser que le préposé doit décrocher le téléphone lorsque celui-ci sonne. Dans le second exemple, la procédure ne précise pas comment les restaurants IN et OUT doivent communiquer pour s'arranger à propos d'un transfert. Il est possible d'être très détaillé mais il faut veiller à ne pas alourdir la tâche avec des informations non pertinentes. L'équipe responsable du recueil de l'information doit adapter ce niveau selon le contexte de chaque processus. 

                \end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

And a screenshot of my problem :

[image: Here is my problem]

Comment: does that screenshot match the posted example? (I get no coloured background when I run your code)

Comment: Latex might not understand how you like to have it, therefore you might want to specify the pagebreak yourself, i.e. add `\newpage` or `\pagebreake` befor the table.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : I cleaned my code but I defined some option for the environment mdframed. Martin : thank you (for the second time today :) )

Comment: But does the posted example show the problem (I get a page break as expected)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : posted example show the problem. No pagebreak for me even with \pagebreak or \newpage

Comment: @DescampsAu if i add it before "Exemple 2" it works (in both cases), where did you put it? Do you want to split the table?

Comment: I get also a page break after "Composantes du processus d'affaires :" in a TeX Live 2013.

Comment: @Martin : it doesn't work. I can cheat by ending mdframed environment, insert a pagebreak and reopen a mdframed environment.

Comment: I get a page break with `Package: mdframed 2013/06/21 1.9a: mdframed` do you have the latest version of mdframed?

Comment: Package: mdframed 2013/07/01 1.9b: mdframed

Maybe a bug with the new version ?

Comment: Hmm I'll update and see...

Answer (score 2):

Using the latest

```
Package: mdframed 2013/07/01 1.9b: mdframed
```

(and the same with the previous 1.9a version) I get this with the posted code:

[image]

Comment: You lucky :) And what if you use my charachteristics of mdframed ? Here :
\definecolor{grisframe}{gray}{0.95}
\definecolor{gristitleframe}{gray}{0.85}
\mdfsetup{backgroundcolor=grisframe, skipabove=12pt, skipbelow=6pt, leftmargin=0pt, rightmargin=0pt, innertopmargin=12pt, innerbottommargin=6pt, innerleftmargin=12pt, innerrightmargin=12pt, frametitleaboveskip=12pt, frametitlebelowskip=6pt, frametitlerule=true, frametitlebackgroundcolor=gristitleframe, splittopskip=2\topsep}

Comment: @DescampsAu I repeatedly asked if the code posted in the question showed the problem. Do you mean it does not?

Comment: It shows the problem, I swear ! I just try to find solutions or problems' roots.

Comment: @DescampsAu the page breaks at the same point with the setting in your comment above/

Comment: In a test file, with the code mentionned above, it works (but didn't before !). Doesn't work in my report. A conflict with a package ?

Comment: I don't understand... here is my tex file : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48560142/memoire.tex
In pdf : page 21. In the report : page 18. In TexMaker : line 299.

Comment: @DescampsAu sorry I'm not downloading/debugging that: standard rules for making an example apply here: start with a copy of the original and delete everything you can while still showing the error.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but the copy didn't work... Now, the copy mentioned above works but my report still not.

Comment: @DescampsAu: The environment `tabularx` can't be splitted.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel : it is not the point. Problem is also with tabular.